# PHP Update mysql Database Table from id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to update data to mysql database i know the query. query is not a problem..

The Problem i am facing is that how should i send id page to other page..

lets suppose i am on page skill_edit.php?id=7
and i click update button then it goes to skills.php from skill_edit.php using POST method of form.

but now how can i send id of page or even id of row in table to "skills.php"

My Database:

[image]

My Form in skill_edit.php

```
     <form class="form-horizontal row-fluid" method="post" action="skills.php">

        <?php //Skill Name ?>
        <div class="form-row control-group row-fluid">
          <label class="control-label span3" for="with-placeholder">Skill Name</label>
          <div class="controls span7">
            <input type="text" name="skill_name" id="with-placeholder" class="row-fluid" value="<?php echo $showskillname; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>

       <?php //Skill Description ?>
        <div class="form-row control-group row-fluid">
          <label class="control-label span3" for="elastic-textarea">Skill Desc <span class="help-block">My Skill Description</span> </label>
          <div class="controls span7">
            <textarea name="skill_desc" rows="3" style=" height:80px;"  class="row-fluid autogrow" id="elastic-textarea"><?php echo $showskilldesc; ?></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <?php //Selecting Language ?>
        <div class="form-row control-group row-fluid">
          <label class="control-label span3">Select with search</label>
          <div class="controls span7">
            <select name="skill_rating" data-placeholder="Choose a Language...." class="chzn-select">
              <option value="<?php echo $showskillrating; ?>"><?php echo $showskillrating; ?></option>
              <option value="1">1 Star</option>
              <option value="2">2 Star</option>
              <option value="3">3 Star</option>
              <option value="4">4 Star</option>
              <option value="5">5 Star</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>


       <?php //Buttons ?>
        <div class="form-actions row-fluid">
          <div class="span7 offset3">
            <button name="updatebtn" style=" float:left; margin-left:40px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            <button formaction="skills.php" style=" float:right; margin-right:40px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

my skill.php page on which i get the data

```
if(isset($_POST['updatebtn']))
{
$updatedskillname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['skill_name']);
$updatedskilldesc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['skill_desc']);
$updatedskillrating = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['skill_rating']);
$last_updated = mysql_real_escape_string(date('F j, Y, g:i a'));

$update=update_skill($updatedskillname, $updatedskilldesc, $updatedskillrating, $last_updated);
}
```

Here is the inside of the function

```
//Update Skill
//skills.php
function update_skill($updatedskillname, $updatedskilldesc, $updatedskillrating, $last_updated)
{
        $query="UPDATE cv_skills SET
                            skill_name='$updatedskillname',
                            skill_desc='$updatedskilldesc',
                            skill_rating='$updatedskillrating',
                            last_updated='$last_updated' WHERE skill_id='$pageid'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$error=mysql_error();

return $error;
}
```

so how can i get skill_id in my query??

Comment: Consider using Session [w3Schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)
Btw, don't send IDs with GET method, use POST instead.

Comment: I suggest passing in the variables as parameter to the function rather then using globals and doing the escaping in the method during query string construction. One small mistake now and you have an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You want to send skill_id on skills.php page ?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" value="id" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple possible ways you can do this but one would be to do:

```
<form class="form-horizontal row-fluid" method="post" action="skills.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
```

This will then post back to itself with the id still in tact. The other way would be you could use a hidden field so you POST the id back to the form.

Hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
```

Comment: Example hidden post: `<input type='hidden' name='postid' value='45'>` and this question completely answers the question, nothing more to be said.

Comment: @Syed Haider Hassan , Tchalvak is right , you can use hidden field , <input type="text" name="skill_id" id="with-placeholder" class="row-fluid" value="<?php echo $showskillid; ?>">

Comment: WoW, Nice. I didn't thought about that..

Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to actually store the id within a session or cookie variable and use it as a qualifier -- but that's for another day.

```
<?php
//create a login form at post to this script at login...

/*
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Email:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="email" /><br /><br />
<label>Password:</label><br />
<input type="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
<label>Remember Me:</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /><br /><br />
</form>
*/

//connect to your database here...
//something like..
include('../includes/db_connection.php');

/*
Table "users" fields would contain userid(int), email(varchars), password(varchars) at a minimum...
*/

$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if(isset($submit)) {

//grab the post info at login...
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

//md5 encryption at a minimum...
$password = md5($password);

//this is just to declare the timeframe for the cookie....
$remember = strip_tags($_POST['remember']);

//query the users table..
//for demo purposes, this is a basic where normally
//I would wrap this into a function.
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

//set-up the userid for the cookie...
$userid = strip_tags($row['userid']);

//if user exists
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0){

//compare the password
if(strcmp($row['password'],$password)==0){

//set the cookie with the the userid...
if (isset($remember)) {

/* Set cookie to last 1 year */
$expire = time()+60*60*24*365;
setcookie('userid', $userid, $expire);        
}

else {

/* Set cookie until the user logs out */
$expire = false;
setcookie('userid', $userid, false); 
}
//send the user over to their secure account...
header('Location: your_secure_login_area.php');

/*
You would then add the following to the top of any secure page that would be applied to the end-user...

<?php
//you can now reference the userid for any db call...
$userid = $_COOKIE['userid'];
if (isset($userid)) {
}
else if(!isset($userid) || $userid == '' || $_GET['userid'] != $_COOKIE['userid']) {
header('Location: http://yourloginpage.php');
}
?>

*/

}
}

else {
$reponse = 'Error: Invalid Information.';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I hear you, but some code with a little sample would not hurt :D

Answer (score 0):

use session or cookie to pass id. as the user can always tamper the id name and modify the value before form submission.